# AutoFiltering by VBA formatted date Cells gives me no result

Tags: excel, vba

Hey im currently trying to automate a work process in Excel.

There is one thing thats not working for me right now.

I am formatting a Column to a Date so i can filter it. i tried it in 2 ways.

v1:

```
Dim a As Long, i As Long
With ZWS 'worksheet name
.Columns(20).NumberFormat = "DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM"
a = .Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 20).End(xlUp).row
For i = a To 2 Step -1
.Cells(i, 20).Value = CDate(.Cells(i, 20).Value)
```

v2:

```
 With ZWS 'worksheet name
.Columns(20).NumberFormat = "DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM"
```

The Column is getting formatted but when i run my VBA filter, which worked when i formatted it by hand, it shows no results but hides everything.

Filter Code:

```
Dim date1 As Date, datum2 As Date
date1 = CDate("16.09.2019")
date2 = CDate("22.09.2019")
With ZWS 'Worksheet name
.Range("T:T"):AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria:=">=" & date1 *1, _
Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & date2
```

I have no idea whats wrong with the code or why it wont filter it when i formatt it in VBA, would be nice if somone has an idead how to solve this in VBA.

Comment: Do you have an `On Error Resume Next` somewhere? Your code should probably error out on `date1 = CDate("16.09.2019")` since `16.09.2019` is not a valid string to process to a date. Replace the dots with a "-".

Comment: Seems like that was the problem. Its working now. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: CDate recognizes date formats according to the locale setting of your system.Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions

Comment: @Jonas To avoid this you can convert your date as double `Cdbl`